# Challenge: Fix a Canvas plugin to work with CORS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, cors

I'm calling on any Canvas experts for help!

I need a jQuery/Canvas plugin fixed. I’m pretty weak on the Canvas side of things.

Basically I want to be able to blur out an image, which I have done using this Canvas script:
http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlur2Demo.html

https://github.com/Quasimondo/QuasimondoJS/blob/master/blur/StackBoxBlur.js

But it doesn’t work with an image hosted on another domain (I have everything on app.example.com and api.example.com). So I need it updated to respect CORS/crossOrigin. I have [documented the issue](https://github.com/Quasimondo/QuasimondoJS/issues/7) with the original developer, but I doubt he is going to fix it (been years since he touched it in a major way).

It would probably be easy hours work for a Canvas guru.

The plugin works by calling this:

```
stackBoxBlurImage( sourceImageID, targetCanvasID, radius, blurAlphaChannel, iterations );
```

I have tried doing this:

```
var img = document.getElementById( imageID );
    img.crossOrigin = '';
var w = img.naturalWidth;
var h = img.naturalHeight;
```

But it doesn't fix the issue.

Ideally I'd like to be able to feed in a `$('.image')` (or just a URL, as I don't need the un-blurred image messing up the DOM), and `$('.canvas')` element, rather than two ID's. That way it could be a little easier to switch out the blurred image on an event (like blurring out an image when the menu opens etc).

If it matters, I'm using this in an Ember app. I don't want to use some sort of PHP proxy script either, seems like the hack way to go.

**UPDATE**

I've added an example of it breaking here:
http://dev.rickanddrew.com/

And the image is here. If you look at response header, CORS is setup correctly I think:
http://image.rickanddrew.com/image.jpg

**ANSWER**

Thanks to Ken below, I figured it out! This is the way I have it running now:

```
function stackBoxBlurImage( imageURL, $canvasObj, radius, blurAlphaChannel, iterations )
{

// Cache vars
var img = document.createElement('img');
var canvas = $canvasObj[0];

// Make it work with CORS
img.crossOrigin = '';
img.src = imageURL;     

// Wait till image loads
img.onload = function(e) {

    // Setup image vars         
    var w = img.naturalWidth;
    var h = img.naturalHeight;

    // Setup Canvas size
    canvas.style.width  = w + "px";
    canvas.style.height = h + "px";
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;

    // Add image to Canvas
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, w, h );
    context.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );    

    // Abort if radius is invalid
    if ( isNaN(radius) || radius < 1 ) return;

    // Blur!
    stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB( canvas, 0, 0, w, h, radius, iterations );
};
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to enable CORS on the origin server. Or check out my **[realtime-blur](https://github.com/epistemex/realtime-blur-js)** which works without any CORS restriction (and it's free).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg I'd love to be able to use CSS blurs, but I can't deal with the inner shadow/white effect it producers. I need the image to fit fullscreen, edge to edge. I do have CORS enabled on server image.

Comment: You say you are allowing anonymous cross-domain serving of the images on your server? If yes, then all you have to do is set the `crossOrigin` flag in javascript and your canvas won't be tainted. You might double check the response headers coming off your image server because it sounds like you haven't set up cross-domain services properly.

Comment: @markE I added an example for you to show you I think CORS is setup right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## #1 CORS order matters

CORS request is not used correctly. As it is now, the image tag's `src` is set, then in the blur script `crossOrigin` is set post:

```
function stackBoxBlurImage( imageID, canvasID, radius, blurAlphaChannel, iterations )
{

    var img = document.getElementById( imageID );   // we already have the image.
        img.crossOrigin = '';                       // too late for this...

    ...
```

This won't work as `crossOrigin` must be set *before* image `src` is set. The CORS usage request is sent together with the URL request (if server doesn't like it, no image for us...).

So to solve, either add `crossOrigin` to the img tag itself:

```
<img id="image" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="image.jpg">
```

or don't set `src` until the JavaScript is loaded if you prefer or need to dynamically set `src` (in which case I would recommend creating the image element dynamically as well):

```
<img id="image">
```

Then:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.crossOrigin = "";
image.onload = blur;
image.src = "image.jpg";

function blur() {
    stackBoxBlurImage( 'image', 'canvas', 30);              
}
```

## #2 Load matters

There is also an issue with how the script is invoked which can prevent the image data from being available (fresh load, no cache, etc.). If the image already exist in the cache this issue is harder to detect (a fresh user to the site will probably not see anything on the first load though..).

Change this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    stackBoxBlurImage( 'image', 'canvas', 30);              
})
```

to:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    stackBoxBlurImage( 'image', 'canvas', 30);
})
```

`ready` only means the DOM is ready, but not necessarily the image data. For that `load` must be used.

There was also an interesting response from the server where an image request seem to be interpreted as plain text. But I did not dig down further as the steps above should be solved first (or maybe I just blinked :) ):

[image: snap]

Comment: Good on you Ken! Thanks! I took what you said and ran with it, check it out here: http://dev.rickanddrew.com/

Comment: @DrewBaker nice, there it is :) Glad I could help!